# How to navigate Fragment from notification in Android Navigation Controller

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

Should i make a Intent that leads to the MainActivity and then navigate function there. or is there another way?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Yeah. first create pending intent point to MainActivity with action and. in Main activity use addOnDestinationChangedListener on navController,  check if action == from notification navigate to the view directly.

Comment: @p.mathew13  you have better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From notification write pending intent to MainActivity and from there navigate to specific fragment using its id

```
val bundle = intent.extras
findNavController(R.id.homeHostFragment)
            .navigate(R.id.notificationsFragment, bundle, null)
```

or

```
    //here homeHostFragment is the id for fragment in xml for which we set the nav graph
    val bundle = intent.extras
    val navHostFragment = homeHostFragment as NavHostFragment
    navHostFragment.navController.navigate(R.id.notificationsFragment,bundle)
```